# How do I open a single URL with no tabs shown with Objective-C, but with an OK button?

Tags: ios, objective-c, safari

I'm trying to open a webpage in order to let users register in my app, but when doing so using openURL

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://example.com"]];
```

A full window of safari is opened, and my URL added to the open tabs.

Is it there any way I can open this single URL, with no tabs or URL bar, but still with navigation controls and a OK button to close the window?

I'm trying to do something similar to how Chrome Custom Tabs work on Android

Comment: Add WKWebView to you screen, make it visible and loarRequest in it. You can place UIButton wherever you want in hide your view. Or you can listen for navigation in WKWebViewNavigationDelegate and react on navigation events on your JS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try `SFSafariViewController` (swift syntax):

```
let safari = SFSafariViewController(url: url)
self.present(safari, animated: false, completion: nil)
```

Just import `SafariServices` for it.

Comment: That did the trick. Objective-C syntax for those still using it: https://gist.github.com/andrassomogyi/1528c4291a4cb5b51de5